# HTML text rendering problem with crystal report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

HI,
I am having problem in rendering html formatted text in crystal report in visual studio 2003.

When the textformat attribute is set to crHTMLText the values are not being displayed in the report.

When it is set to crRTFText the formatting is not applied.

Is there anything I should do for achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but this is a straight copy and paste from the Crystal Reports help file from version 11.5 under Text Interpretation. The options are none, RTF, or HTML. HTML works to some degree, but not all tags are supported. I also found out that for the BR tag `<br>` works, but `<br />` is not interpreted correctly.

So, to make `<br />` into `<br>`, I had to use the following formula:
`Replace ({LONGDESCRIPTION.LDTEXT}, "<br />", "<br>")`

```
The supported HTML tags are:

html 
body 
div (causes a paragraph break) 
tr (causes only a paragraph break; does not preserve column structure of a table) 
span 
font 
p (causes a paragraph break) 
br (causes a paragraph break) 
h1 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & twice default size) 
h2 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 1.5 times default size) 
h3 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 9/8 default size) 
h4 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold) 
h5 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/6 default size) 
h6 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/8 default size) 
center 
big (increases font size by 2 points) 
small (decreases font size by 2 points if it's 8 points or larger) 
b 
i 
s 
strike 
u 


The supported attributes are:

align 
face 
size 
color 
style 
font-family 
font-size 
font-style 
font-weight
```

Comment: some font size will be set 1 to 7 only, example :  "Batch : " + "<font size=6>" + {tbl_Student_Info.Batch} + "</font>"

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting this property through code? With the designer, I believe it's the "text interpretation" property found in the paragraph tab. I know only a small subset of html tags are supported.

Comment: Ya only some of the HTML tags are rendered. Tags like table, div etc are not rendered. So the design wont be effective. Can you suggest any other way of presenting a large string in pages as in MS word.

Comment: I take it this is a desktop app? Maybe the .Net web-browser control would work good for this? Or, just launch whatever the default browser is. You could simply put the text in a temp file and open that with the browser.